# Numbers larger than long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java

I was just wondering what would be best for storing a very very large integer, and if there are multiple options, what the advantages and disadvantages of it are compared to the others.

I want to store and work with this value:

```
116738484849595836625273748485838625252737485884625292837367283849484726373884848484636377473636252626736363636637373747
```

Comment: Out of interest, what will you use this number for?

Comment: I want to take different segments of the number and compare them to each other. I'm just doing this for learning purposes.

Comment: If you want to compare the decimal representation and look for repeats for example, just leave it as a String of digits and compare sections e.g. by using a NavigableSet to sort similar sections together.

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you very much. I am also wanting to compare the result of different mathematical functions on the sections which is why I thought I would have to represent it as a class that has mathematical methods within.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to analyse the number based on its *String representation*, I would leave it as a String.  Doing the same thing with BigInteger is much harder.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) {
    String s = "116738484849595836625273748485838625252737485884625292837367283849484726373884848484636377473636252626736363636637373747";
    NavigableSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        set.add(s.substring(i));
    String prev = "", longest = "";
    for (String t : set) {
        int len = startMatchingLength(prev, t);
        if (len > longest.length())
            longest = t.substring(0, len);
        prev = t;
    }

    System.out.println("Longest match was " + longest);
}

public static int startMatchingLength(String s, String t) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() && i < t.length();i++)
        if (s.charAt(i) != t.charAt(i))
            return i;
    return Math.min(s.length(), t.length());
}
```

prints

```
Longest match was 25273748
```

Comment: @JakeArnold Its important to remember that a number can have a String representation which includes its "base" and formatting like leading zeros or commas, and this is a textural information. e.g. phone numbers are best represented as Strings as they can include symbols such as leading zeros, `+` `(` `)` and space. If you want to do a numeric analysis like finding its factors, the format is irrelevant and it is better to do this as a number such as `long`, `double`, `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for arbitrary length integers.

Comment: Thanks for the very fast response. I will use this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BigInteger` form `java.math` package it has the predefined mathematical functions.

here is a reference for it [JavaDoc Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 1):

If its only for Integers, I would recommend a look at `java.math.BigInteger`.
It features a contructor for `String` which enables you to use integers of arbitrary (of course memory limited) length and perform basic algebraic operations.

But: It also depends on that you define as "working" with it.
Maybe just building a String of that value also suffices your requirements.

Comment: I will look into using String, but some of the segments of the number that I check may be larger than long.MAX_VALUE and I need to apply mathematical functions to them.

Comment: In this case, BigInteger is the way to go.